# Different jQuery versions in development and production

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am working on a Meteor app with Mantra specification. I am having a problem with jQuery versions. Here's the scenario:

My packages in my `.meteor`folder includes twbs:bootstrap and jquery. At the same time, I have npm packages that depend on jquery.

When I run `$.fn.jquery` in my local environment, it returns a `2.2.4`. But when it is deployed on staging site, it returns `3.0.0`.

How do I figure out the wrong one here? The console throws an error : "Bootstrap Javascript requires jQuery 1.9.1 or higher, but less than 3." Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the oldest version but certify to set the jquery before any script

Comment: How do I know which version to remove? I can't even see jquery itself on meteor packages

Comment: could you send a link with the code?

Comment: Keep the version that is "*1.9.1 or higher, but less than 3*" You have `v2.2.4` and `v3.0.0` One of those is >= 1.9.1 && < 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

you maight solve it using `jQuery.noConflict()`  [read the user guide here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    }); 
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
 </script>
```